# How to save relations of same class?

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I had problem with saving relation to object with same class as parent.
You can check this problem [here](http://jsbin.com/qunutuja/4/edit).

When I read that I can easily set the relationship after the promise has fulfilled [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/creating-and-deleting-records/) I created another [example](http://jsbin.com/sozan/1/edit) with that info in mind. But it doesn't work as I expect.

**What I expect**
Create array of Box instances with relation to previous Box instance in each.

**And the question is** if I'm doing something wrong or it's a bug. Let me know if you need any informations.

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't clear and simple enough. It needs to be isolated to *EXACTLY* what you're having an issue about and nothing else.

Having said that, I have had quite a bit of success saving relations to objects with the same class as parent, and so I don't think this is a problem with Ember Data or Ember.

Your code is quite convoluted and uses the sync library, which I'm not faimilar with.

It's a good idea to things as simply as possible at first, so try creating a jsbin with just the isolated functionality relating to saving relations that you're attempting, and then adding additional layers of functionality and testing after each add.

Comment: I should provide more info in the evening then.